# checking if javascript array contains value using underscorejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of cars like this:

```
[{ name:"Toyota Minivan", id:"506" }, { name:"Honda Civic", id:"619" }]
```

I am trying to check whether the array contains a certain id.

I have tried

```
var x =!!_.where(cars, {id:'506'}).length;
```

expecting it to return true if the array contains the id, but it always returns false.

What am I doing here ?

Btw, I don't have to use underscore.js if there is a better way of doing this.

thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code does work (once you fix the syntax errors in the object array):
http://jsfiddle.net/ArPCa/

```
var cars = [{ name:"Toyota Minivan", id:"506"}, { name:"Honda Civic", id:"619"}];
var x =!!_.where(cars, {id:'506'}).length;
console.log('value: ' + x);
```

returns "value: true". So there must be a problem somewhere else.

But, a better way to do this might be `some`:

```
var y = _.some(cars, function(c) {
    return c.id == '506'; 
});
```

Comment: you were right. The problem was, that I passed the id as a string and I should have passed an int. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I know this is late, but even easier:

```
var cars = [{ name:"Toyota Minivan", id:"506"}, { name:"Honda Civic", id:"619"}];

function findById(id) {
  return _.contains(_.pluck(cars, 'id'), id);
}
```

Comment: Runtime here is weird. Pluck wraps map, so you essentially make a selective copy of the array content, then iterate over that new copy to find your match. Kind of twice the work.

Answer (score 4):

Say you have the array `arr`, and your id, `id`.

```
arr.filter(function(elem) { return elem.id == id; });
```

will return an array with the matching element(s);

You could wrap it in a function like:

```
function findById(arr, id) {
 var filtered = arr.filter(function(elem) { return elem.id == id; });
 return filtered && filtered.length ? filtered[0] : null;
}
```

, potentially doing some other stuff if you weren't happy with the default filtered array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = [{
    name: "Toyota Minivan",
    id: "506"
}, {
    name: "Honda Civic",
    id: "619"
}];

function findCar(id) {
    return obj.filter(function (car) {
        if (car.id == id) {
            return car;
        }
    });
}
```